# Рекурсия в регулярных выражениях

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, java

Здравствуйте.
Есть регулярное выражение (для примера)

```
/ \( ( [^)(]+ | (?R) )+ \) /x
```

**(?R)** означает рекурсивную ссылку на само регулярное выражение, где можно найти обработчик регулярных выражений, поддерживающих такие рекурсии для Java или Python ?
Стандартные `java.util.regex` и питоновский `regex` кажется не имеют поддержки этого механизма.
Регулярное выражение взято [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/56765/).

Comment: мосх можно сломать =)

Comment: Да это же парсер лиспа! :)
Аналогичный вопрос: [How can a recursive regexp be implemented in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656859/how-can-a-recursive-regexp-be-implemented-in-python)

Comment: @gordio, на стеке вместо движка регулярных выражений предлагают использовать pyparsing, что совсем не то.  
Автор поста на Хабре использует Perl кстати, насчет лиспа ничего не скажу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex
Альтернативный движок для регулярных выражений питона с поддержкой рекурсий.

Java движка кажется не существует в настоящее время.